# Weebly Migration to Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, migration, weebly

I have some Weebly pages that I'd like to migrate to a new domain I set up for Wordpress. I've tried a couple of methods such as exporting an XML file or using CMS2CMS, but they all seem like they require FTP access, which Weebly unceremoniously prevents their users from accessing.

Does anyone have any tips on Weebly migration to Wordpress? It would save me a lot of work formatting my pages from scratch.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I used weeblytowp, which was able to export my Weebly files as an XML, which I could import into Wordpress. The trick was to copy my Weebly site onto a Weebly subdomain (e.g. subdomain.weebly.com), and then do the transfer on weeblytowp. It doesn't seem to work with a non-weebly domain.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there's no need to provide Weebly FTP access when migrating from Weebly platform using CMS2CMS automated migration service. You will be asked only WordPress FTP details. Maybe, you'd better try once more or consult their support team, they are always open to help.